# IntersectObjects not returning a result

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm using trying to establish whether a ray intersects an object in three.js

My scene is setup and display nicely.

I click on the sphere I created as follows:

```
var intersect_objects = [];

//Initialize scene and object and events

scene = new THREE.Scene();
group = new THREE.Object3D();
sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(23.8, 60, 60);

//Add meshes and textures etc..

intersect_objects.push(group);

function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var mouseX = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth)*2-1;
    var mouseY = -(event.clientY /window.innerHeight)*2+1;

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouseX, mouseY, 0.5);
    projector.unprojectVector(vector, camera);

    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects(intersect_objects);

    console.log(intersects.length); //Aways 0

}
```

But intersects.length is always 0. Surely it intersects the sphere?

Answer (score 0):

The intersection code looks fine; are you sure that "group" has been added to "scene" and "sphere" has been added to "group" correctly? Without seeing the rest of your code, it is impossible to determine what the error might be.  Please consider creating a jsfiddle containing complete code.

Also, perhaps try testing this with ray.intersectObjects(scene.children) to see if anything at all will register a collision.

Comment: Thanks Lee, http://jsfiddle.net/kDQHV/

I have a 'container' in a window. I have a suspicion that my mouseX & mouseY is calculated incorrectly because I'm not accounting for the container being inside a window.

Comment: Note that intersectsObject doesn't take into account rotation of the mesh.